# How do you cast to an unsigned int in polars?

Tags: python-polars

I tried `pl.col('foo').cast(np.uint32)` and I got a NotImplementedError.

I ask because `col.str.lengths()` returns a column of type `UInt32` and columns need to be the same type for joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polars is not numpy, so you need a polars `dtype` when casting.

```py
>>> s = pl.Series("a", [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> s
```

```
shape: (5,)
Series: 'a' [i64]
[
    -1
    0
    1
    2
    3
]
```

```py
>>> s.cast(pl.UInt32, strict=False)
```

```
shape: (5,)
Series: 'a' [u32]
[
    null
    0
    1
    2
    3
]
```

The default casting behaviour is `strict`. This would raise an error in this case, because we cannot cast negative integers to unsigned integers.